# Android - groups with profiles (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase

Do u know if there is a tutorial for android/firebase how to create a Todo-List or a Shopping List which is connected to others?

For example:
User A created a group. User B and C join this group and so they can edit the same Todo-List.

Or do u have an idea how do solve this problem at easiest way? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is. The course can be found here, [Firebase Essentials For Android](https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009). An the project on github, can be found [here](https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus).

Hope it helps.